# Shortcut to open Windows 10 On-Screen Keyboard (not OSK.exe)

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, on-screen-keyboard

Is it possible to open the newest Windows 10 on-screen Keyboard (not OSK.exe) with a shortcut?

I mean the one in the notification bar, this one:

[image: Screen Shot]

That pops automatically when you don't have a keyboard.

Not OSK.exe (it looks similar, but is not the same).

I only can open it currently clicking on the icon in the notification bar.

Comment: I would refer you to [this](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/6-ways-to-turn-on-on-screen-keyboard-in-windows-10.html) how-to, but apparently it interprets "On Screen Keyboard" as osk. Please detail what differences the two present to you and why you need one and NOT the other.

Comment: Three out of those six ways were fake; the reiterated method 3.

Comment: @simlev the OSK doesn't have extended ascii codes for emojis and that. But the new W10 On-Screen touch keyboard does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution worked for me so it might be worth a try:

- Go onto the desktop and select new -> shortcut
- Within the "Type the Location of the item" text box add the following:

  %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip.exe

[image: Shortcut Link]

- Hit the next button, and name your shortcut to something of your choosing.

[image]

- Double click and run your "Touch Keyboard"

I followed the instructions from this site and it worked perfectly for me (With the emojis too!) It does state Windows 8 but appears to work on 10 too.

[Touch Keyboard Shortcut Instructions](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/16909-touch-keyboard-shortcut-create-windows-8-a.html)

Let me know how you get on :)

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot create a shortcut (like on a borrowed PC or a temporary account) then a workaround is to press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to put focus into the notification area. After that change the focus to the keyboard button (with arrow keys) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you don't have a lot of icons in the notification area then it'll take just a few keystrokes to open the keyboard which may still be faster than reaching the mouse, click then back again to your home row

But nowadays to enter emojis and such just press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>. (dot)</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>; (semicolon)</kbd>

[image: Emoji input]

[image: Emoji input]

[How do I bring up the emoji IME on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1255287/241386)

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I had no idea there was a standalone emoji window.