# How do I bring up the emoji IME on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm running Windows 10, edition: Windows 10 Pro, version: 1703, OS Build: 15063.608.

According to [several](http://blog.getemoji.com/emoji-keyboard-windows) [articles](https://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2017/06/09/windows-10-now-emoji-shorcut-time/) around the net I should be able to press 
<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to bring up an emoji IME that looks like this

[image: windows 10 emoji ime]

But when I press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> nothing happens. When I press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> the magnifier shows up even though in settings magnifier is turned off.

How do I get the emoji IME to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new [feature of the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update 1709](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/06/08/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16215-pc-build-15222-mobile/) and not of your Creators Update 1703.

So you have to install the last Insider Build or wait for the final of the v1709 which gets released on [17th October 2017](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/09/01/create-and-play-this-holiday-with-the-windows-10-fall-creators-update-coming-oct-17/).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Taskbar. Select *"Show Touch Keyboard Button."*

[image: Taskbar Right click on win10]

Now click on the touch keyboard Icon on right side of your taskbar.  (system tray). Then Click the face Icon on Keyboard.

[image: touch keyboard]