# Windows 10 equivalent of Mac Command+Control+Space

Tags: windows-10, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, emoji, emoji-keyboard

On Mac version Maverics onwards there is an emoji shortcut of <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Is there an equivalent of emoji shortcut for Windows 10?

[image: emoji-shortcut]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I bring up the emoji IME on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1255287/how-do-i-bring-up-the-emoji-ime-on-windows-10)

Comment: Didn't see that one, thanks phuclv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Windows computer, use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> for the emoji keyboard to be displayed.

[image: Emojis on Windows]