# Shortcut to pop up emoji window automatically

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window, emoji

Sometimes I want to pop the emoji, but it's cumbersome because I need to right click and then click "Emoji". Is there some shortcut to automatically pop up emoji? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: duplicate: [Windows 10 equivalent of Mac Command+Control+Space](https://superuser.com/q/1628332/241386), [On Windows, is there an equivalent to the MacOS system-wide emoji selector overlay (cmd+opt+space)?](https://superuser.com/q/1771955/241386)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Anaksunaman](https://superuser.com/users/302907/anaksunaman) for the [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1712502/shortcut-to-pop-up-emoji-window-automatically/1712503#comment2640059_1712502). The method is the <kbd>Window</kbd> key followed by a <kbd>period</kbd>.